# Dynamic Select in RubyOnRails error in append select

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I'm trying to do a dynamic select, when user select school appear only the groups that belong to that school, but when I tried to change the select I got this error:

> Missing partial admin/groups/_group with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee]}.

**CoffeeScript**

```
$(document).on "page:change", ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#schools_select', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'update_groups',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        school_id: $("#schools_select option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{errorThrown}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        console.log("Dynamic school select OK!")
```

**HTML**

The school belongs to the model of the form, but the group isn't an attribute of the form.

```html
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :school %><br>
      <%= f.select :school_id, options_for_select(@schools.active.collect { |school|
      [school.name.titleize, school.id] }, 1), {}, { id: 'schools_select' } %>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= label_tag :group %><br>
      <%= select_tag :group_id, options_for_select(@groups.active.collect { |group|
      [group.name.titleize, group.id] }, 1), { id: 'groups_select' } %>
    </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#groups_select").empty().append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @groups)) %>")
```

**Ruby**

```
 def update_groups
   @groups = Group.where(school_id: params[:school_id])
   respond_to do |format|
     format.js
   end
 end
```

**Routes**

```
     get 'students/update_groups', as: 'update_groups'
```

Comment: try to change `format.js` to `format.json`, i think u dnt have that `_group.html.erb` page.

Comment: You use a `respond_to` block but don't tell it what to render. It will try to render a template file by default, which might be the cause for the "Missing partial" error. Maybe you wanted to use `format.json { render json: @groups }` within that respont_to block?

Comment: @7urkm3n If change `format.js` to `format.json` now the missing file is other `Missing template admin/students/update_groups, application/update_groups with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee]}. Searched in:`. I add _update_groups.html.erb and update_groups.html.erb and still not working.

Comment: As @Raffael suggested, I change the respond_to `respond_to do |format| format.json { render json: @groups } end` and the missing partial error was solved, but now the second select didn't refresh when the first select change.

Comment: Checking your browser's Javascript console might give you hints as to why stuff does not work as expected. Use `console.log` in your Ajax callback handlers. Please research more about Javascript debugging yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My error was that I didn't tell what to render and then I was trying to update the select in other file, when it wasn't necessary.

This is the updated code

**CofeeScript**

```
$(document).on "page:change", ->
  $(document).on 'change', '#schools_select', (evt) ->
    $.ajax 'update_groups',
      type: 'GET'
      dataType: 'script'
      data: {
        school_id: $("#schools_select option:selected").val()
      }
      error: (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) ->
        console.log("AJAX Error: #{errorThrown}")
      success: (data, textStatus, jqXHR) ->
        groups = JSON.parse(data)
        $.each groups, (index) ->
          $('#groups_select').empty().append $('<option></option>').attr('value', groups[index].id).text(groups[index].name)
        return
```

**Ruby**

```
  def update_groups
    @groups = Group.where(school_id: params[:school_id])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { render json: @groups }
    end
  end
```

I delete the javascript file.

Answer (score 1):

Make your method like below. Also, make sure yr ajax request triggers.

```
def update_groups
   @groups = Group.where(school_id: params[:school_id])
   render json: @groups, root: false
 end
```

Comment: this render works but now the group select didn't refresh with the data of the selected school.

Comment: now u need to handle that `response` success data from ajax, logic where u do `.append` thing.

Comment: also, `$("#groups_select").empty().append("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @groups)) %>")` you dnt need this one, i dnt know where do u keep it. Its good use with `format.js`. if u have that files like `create.js.erb` etc... Now u holding $AJAX, just use that one put yr own logic into success part.